# Is numpy slower than c++ linear algebra libraries like eigen?

Tags: c++, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, linear-algebra

I use it to implement neural networks. I prefer NumPy, because it is more convenient to prepare data with Python; however, I am concerned that NumPy is not as fast as c++ libraries.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Python is slower than C++.

Comment: Better rule of thumb: Python is definitely slower than C++ at computation.

Comment: Buf numpy is implemented in C as Mike muler said below?

Comment: Python was implemented in C, but Python is slow.

Comment: Really? Man, I don't think that is a good point.

Comment: It depends. If you have a well-tuned BLAS implementation, numpy will call into that, and that can be faster than Eigen. For instance on my machine I'm getting 200 G ops/sec on matrix multiplies using numpy, and only 160 G ops/sec using Eigen, with the reason being that my BLAS is better optimized (using OpenBLAS which uses openmp, vs using Eigen tensor library which relies on threadpools)

Comment: I tried mkl today, I thought it would be better than openBlas but not. How do you count the number of ops?

Comment: @erip Sorry, but I think that your comments, in the context of this question, are terribly misleading. Pure-Python's performance is nearly irrelevant for practical numerical work.

Comment: @AmiTavory You may disagree and that's fine. Perhaps I was thinking in the frame of "out of the box guarantees". I'm pretty sure numpy is still slower than Eigen/LAPACK _off the shelf_. Once you start fiddling, it may be comprable, but at that point OP is losing the "convenience factor" of Python.

Comment: @erip I'm not even sure that I agree with your last comment (e.g., which Eigen/LAPACK C++: GSL, MKL? There's a huge variance), but your first comments are a different matter entirely. In any case, I guess we'll agree to disagree; all the best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NumPy is implemented in C. So most of the time you just call C and for some functionality optimized Fortran functions or subroutines. Therefore, you will get a decent speed with NumPy for many tasks. You need to vectorize your operations. Don't write `for` loops over NumPy arrays. Of course, hand-optimized C code can be faster. On the other hand, NumPy contains a lot of already optimized algorithms that might be faster than not so optimal C code written by less experienced C programmers.

You can gradually move from Python to C with [Cython](http://cython.org/) and/or use [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)
for jit-compilation to machine or gpu code.

Answer (score 6):

I have to say that I think that the other answers here are missing things.

First, as @Mike Muller correctly points out, Python's numerical libraries have C or Fortran (or both) backends, so the performance of pure-Python is almost irrelevant (as opposed to the performance of the backend, which can be significant). In this respect, whether you're manipulating something like [`MKL`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) through Python or C++ - hardly makes a difference.

There are two differences, though:

- On the plus side for Python - it is interactive. This means that, especially in conjunction with something like the [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html), you can perform an operation and plot the result, perform another operation and plot the result, etc. It's hard to get this effect for exploratory analysis with a compiled language like   C++ or Java.
- On the minus side for Python - it, and its scientific ecosystem, handle multicores imperfectly, to say the least. This is a fundamental problem of the language itself  (read about the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)).

Comment: Your points are very reasonable to me. Also I want to know whether using a more deep learning specific toolkit like tensorflow,cntk, etc will lead to more efficient?

Comment: On the interactivity point: C++ now has a Jupyter kernel: https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus